# Similar C strings have varying sizes

Tags: c, string, pointers, types, sizeof

I have a function which takes an argument of type `const unsigned char *` as one of its inputs.

Function (mentioned below)

`someType *doSomething (someStruct *, const unsigned char *);`
or `judyData *getFromJudy (judyConfig *, const unsigned char *)`.

I also have an array of strings , `char* i[10]`.

Suppose, `i[2] = "foo"`. Now, I get different results when I run

`doSomething(struct_instance, i[2])` and `doSomething(struct_instance, "foo")`.

Can anyone help me out with when do such situations arise?
Is there a way to type cast the value this pointer points to such that it behaves like a normal string literal?

EDIT:

Sharing code samples.

The function:

```
// get an entry from the index, return it or null
judyData *getFromJudy (judyConfig *cnf, const unsigned char *key) {
  judyData *data;
  JudySlot *cell;
  int current;
      cell = judy_slot((Judy *) cnf->idx, (unsigned char *) key, (size_t) strlen((const char *) key));

  if (cell) {
    data = (judyData *) *cell;
    // doesn't enter this if "foo" is not used and i[2] is used.
    if (data->count == 0) {
      return NULL;
    }

    return data;
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

with `char * i[10]`. It is called as

`data = getFromJudy (obj, "foo")`

Comment: `sizeof(i[2])` doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: `i[2]` is a pointer, not an array.

Comment: @Barmar What does just "foo" represent then?

Comment: `"foo"` is a string literal, which is like an array.

Comment: `printf("%lu\n", sizeof(i[2]));` --> `printf("%zu\n", strlen(i[2]) + 1);` --> `4`

Comment: The code in the edit doesn't seem to have anything to do with the rest of the question

Comment: @M.M Its the function I've mentioned.

Comment: So many cast, "Oh dear we are in trouble!".

Comment: I'm sensing that your real question is "why does `i[2] = "foo"; getFromJudy(bla, i[2]);` behave differently to `getFromJudy(bla, "foo");`?"  If so then you should edit your question to remove the question about `sizeof`, which literally has nothing to do with that issue. Also you should include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Perfect example, of [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Done the editing. It would be good if anyone has any insight on this.

Comment: @saruftw You are far away of a good question, read [mcve]. I want be able to copy and past your code and that must compile ! (only code not compilation linker ofc). What is these `judy` structure for example.

Comment: You need a MCVE because there is no difference in the defined behaviour between the two options you've described, so the most likely explanation is that you already caused undefined behaviour (either in your own code, or due to a bug in the judy library). The only way to proceed is to find where the bug is, and to do so requires seeing a complete program that exhibits the bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof(i[2])` returns the size of a pointer on your machine, which is eight bytes, since it is of type `char *`; `sizeof("foo")` returns the length of the string "foo" plus the null terminator, which is four bytes.

Comment: Somehow, the function doesn't behave accordingly. I want the function to behave as it would with "foo" as the argument. How can I make change to the passing of i[2] as an argument?

Comment: @saruftw Luckily, you're concerned with strings, so you can use `strlen`; that's what it's there for.

Comment: @saruftw You can't. Pointers don't carry information about the size of the object they point to.

Comment: @Barmar In the general case, you're right, but strings have the null-terminator which allows for library functions liked `strlen`.

Comment: Is there a way to type cast the value this pointer points to such that it behaves like a normal string literal?

Comment: @saruftw That sounds like an appropriate topic for a new question.

Comment: @saruftw No, it's not possible. Pointers and arrays are completely different things. Arrays can decay to pointers, but there's no way to go the other way because the information simply isn't there.

Comment: @saruftw If you're just dealing with strings, why don't you want to use `strlen()`?

Comment: @saruftw Why don't you just give the length to your function ?

Comment: I'm unable to gauge the issue I'm facing here. The function doesn't behave correctly with i[2] as it does with "foo" and that's what I'm trying to solve. @Barmar what do you mean by using strlen()?

Comment: @saruftw What exactly do you mean by "doesn't behave correctly"?

Comment: @saruftw Add the function you're trying to write to the question, and we can help you fix it.

Comment: @saruftw If you want to know how many characters there are in a string, use `strlen(string)`. This works with a pointer or array.